# Signing a user in through ASP.NET Membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

As mentioned in [this link](http://chandradev819.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-password-in-asp-net-using-c/)

I have hashed the password and stored LogIn details in my Database table.

Now I'm using LogIn page of already existing ASP.NET page (through Account folder that is in-built).. How do I make this page to interact with my DB and redirect to his/her profile?

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  Until you at least post what you have tried and explain what results you recieved I have to downvote this question.  The only thing you need to do is supply the username and password, if you don't have the password, then you cannot log into the ASP.NET Membership Role User account in question.  You could of course write your own provider that could

Comment: @Ramhound I have my own form for Registering the User (employee of my organization). Now I am using the already existing form in ASP.NET Web app, "LogIn.aspx". I do not know how to make this form to interact with the DB and Logs in the user..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `asp.net membership` provider

After you obtain the username and password you can call [Membership.ValidateUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.validateuser.aspx) method.

eg

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(userName.Text, password.Text))
{
  if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] != null)
  {
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName.Text, false);
  }
  else
  {
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName.Text, false);
  }
}
else
{
  Response.Write("Invalid UserID and Password");
}
```

Read more about [Use Membership in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx)